# How to scrape data that appear when click on button?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape phone numbers from website, but the numbers will appear only if I click on the first number. In other words, the phone will be hidden in the HTML code, and when I click it will appear. can you help please?
I used the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://hipages.com.au/connect/makermanservices"

req = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(req,"html.parser")

phone = soup.find('a', class_='PhoneNumber__MobileOnly-sc-4ewwun-1 izNnbI phone-number__mobile')
print(phone)
```

Comment: Probably you have to analyze JavaScript code that shows the number or user some library like Selenium. Beautifulsoup is not suitable for this task.

Comment: In javascript you could do something like `document.querySelector('.phone-number__mobile').click()`, but you would have to automate it with Selenium as @MichaelButscher already mentioned

Comment: I am trying to do it without selenium

Comment: @AhmadTamimi You cannot use Beautiful Soup alone to click on an element and get its text content. Beautiful Soup is a Python library for parsing HTML and XML documents, but it does not have the capability to interact with a website in the way that Selenium does.

Comment: may I use: requests.post(url, data = payload)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little bit of hacking, you can get the phone number with the help of `bs4` and `pandas`.

For example:

```py
import json
import re

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://hipages.com.au/connect/makermanservices"
script_text = "window.__INITIAL_PROPS__="

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/112.0.1722.48",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "lxml")
script = soup.find("script", string=lambda t: t and script_text in t)
data = json.loads(re.search(script_text + r"(.+)", script.string).group(1))
df = (
    pd.read_json(data)
    ["fetchKey-7-0-0_/connect/makermanservices"]
    ["site"]
    ["primary_location"]
    ["phone"]
)
print(df)
```

This should print:

```
1800 801 828
```